# Fixed index when resorting table

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm trying to find a way to use Tablesorter to sort a top records list, but still remain a 1 - 100 ranking list (ie. not keeping the position when resortin gthe table).

Lets say we have a top 100 list of users with different values for each user.

The list can look something like this (as they don't allow markdown tables here this was the best I could do):

### Rank | Name | Score | Avg Score

1 | Joe | 101 | 55

2 | Max | 98 | 87

3 | Susie | 78 | 34

4 | Amy | 65 | 12

When I sort by Name, or any other elements in the table, I wish the Rank number to still be 1 - 4 from the top, not sorted by the rest of the data.

Is this possible to do in a good way in Tablesorter, or am I required to make a specific function myself after the sorting is done to make it possible?

Comment: Check out the "numbering" widget in the second half of my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason this solution does not work with combined widgets, like `widgets: ['tableNumbering','zebra']`
Without the extra widget, zebra works without an issue.

Comment: It works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9581/

Comment: Must be something on my end then, thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Forgot to change the number_column statement in `$(this).find('td').eq(number_column).text(i + 1);` to `$(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i + 1);`